# Error build ipa from android studio, but work well on xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, build, ipa

i need to build .ipa fila from flutter project on my Macbook.
I always get error when run build .ipa from android studio, but when i try on xcode it can success build and export .ipa file.

This is error log for that :

```
rahmad@Rahmads-MacBook-Air ios % flutter build ipa --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
Changing current working directory to: /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise

 Building with sound null safety 

Archiving com.cdn.mantra.dev...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: J8FAKZW
Running pod install...                                           2,147ms
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode archive done.                                         37.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/kp/vm23k0rx5r7cwwn73dmdcs640000gn/T/flutter_tools.xjy4ef/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirpFWZuS/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /var/folders/kp/vm23k0rx5r7cwwn73dmdcs640000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-GQ6JxC.sh: line 3: /.envfile: Read-only file system
    /var/folders/kp/vm23k0rx5r7cwwn73dmdcs640000gn/T/SchemeScriptAction-GQ6JxC.sh: line 4: /.symlinks/plugins/flutter_config/ios/Classes/BuildXCConfig.rb: No such file or directory
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m:87:14: warning: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
                 ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:260:34: note: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets API_DEPRECATED("Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead", ios(7.0,11.0),tvos(7.0,11.0)); // Defaults to YES
                                     ^
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.m:1299:36: warning: 'topLayoutGuide' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
    [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
                statusBarHeight = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
                                       ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIViewController.h:505:58: note: 'topLayoutGuide' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    @property(nonatomic,readonly,strong) id<UILayoutSupport> topLayoutGuide API_DEPRECATED("Use view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor instead of topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor", ios(7.0,11.0), tvos(7.0,11.0));
                                                             ^
    2 warnings generated.
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:39:52: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDataSource: class {
                                                       ^~~~~
                                                       AnyObject
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:55:50: warning: using 'class' keyword to define a class-constrained protocol is deprecated; use 'AnyObject' instead
    internal protocol DKPhotoGalleryContentDelegate: class {
                                                     ^~~~~
                                                     AnyObject
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGallery/DKPhotoGalleryContentVC.swift:107:14: warning: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead
            self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
                 ^
    /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/DKImagePickerController/Sources/DKImagePickerController/View/DKAssetGroupDetailVC.swift:344:14: warning: 'frameInterval' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: preferredFramesPerSecond
            link.frameInterval = 1
                 ^
    /Users/rahmad/work/master/flutter3_0_0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-4.6.1/ios/Classes/FilePickerPlugin.m:357:1: warning: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]
    - (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url{
    ^
    In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/file_picker/file_picker-prefix.pch:2:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDocumentPickerViewController.h:27:1: note: method 'documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL:' declared here
    - (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url API_DEPRECATED_WITH_REPLACEMENT("documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:", ios(8.0, 11.0));
    ^
    1 warning generated.
    /Users/rahmad/work/master/flutter3_0_0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/file_picker-4.6.1/ios/Classes/FileUtils.m:133:30: warning: unused variable 'exportError' [-Wunused-variable]
                        NSError *exportError = exporter.error;
                                 ^
    1 warning generated.
    ../master/flutter3_0_0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-2.4.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
        FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../master/flutter3_0_0/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-14.2.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:128:22: Error: A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be returned from a function with return type 'bool'.
     - 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
        return _delegate.isSupported();
                         ^
    Failed to package /Users/rahmad/work/mantra-flutter-enterprise.
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target
    'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in
    target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Copy GoogleInfoPlist' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase.
    (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/kp/vm23k0rx5r7cwwn73dmdcs640000gn/T/flutter_tools.xjy4ef/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirpFWZuS/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Uncategorized (Xcode): Exited with status code 127


Encountered error while archiving for device.
```

I have 2 weeks for try solving this, but still not have solution.

I hope you can help me to build .ipa from android studio successfully.

Comment: When you have XCode installed, why do you want to want to build ipa from Android Studio.

Comment: @Prashant i need to test run script build .ipa from CLI, and then i will implement it on github workflow for automation deployment.